# Ajax TabContainer third tabpanel is not displaying in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, tabpanel

i am using asp.net ajax tab container. i have added six tab panel but third tab panel is not displaying in browser. i have used this inside a user control. Even i moved panel back and forth but panel always on third position is not display. i search this on google but did found any solution.

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="EmpTabContainer" runat="server"  ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="100%">

<asp:TabPanel ID="ActivePanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Active"  Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>



</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="OnLeavePanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="OnLeave"   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="TerminatedPanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label53" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Terminated"   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="ResignedPanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Resigned"   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="BlockedPanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Blocked"   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>


</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="DidNotJoinPanel"  runat="server" Font-Bold="true" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="NotJoined"   Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>


</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>

</asp:TabContainer>

 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code(tab-container + TabPanels, first without content if it's too much) so that we can try to help.

Comment: Dear see my user control markup

Comment: @user3867782 for clarification: `TabPanel` _TerminatedPanel_ doesn't get displayed ?

Comment: Yes currently terminated panel is not displaying but when i move another panel to this position then that panel is not displaying.

Comment: Even if you remove the content of the panel?

Comment: Yes even when i removed the contents still not showing.

Comment: Dears anyone have solution for this please update.